# Non-Object Oriented Programming in Object Oriented Language

Tags: c++, object-oriented

Recently I was assigned a task of creating a calculator with functions addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and power using **Object Oriented Programming**. I successfully completed this task. However afterwards I reprogrammed the whole program without using Object Oriented *technique/method*.

The thing I noticed that my code length was reduced quite significantly and it was quite understandable. So my question here is when should I use Object Oriented Programming? Is it okay to create programs without Object Orientation in Object Oriented Language? Kindly help me out on this one.

PS: I am not asking here to tell me merits of Object Oriented Programming over procedural programming.

Comment: Are you looking for an absolute answer here? Not gonna find it.

Comment: @ChaosPandion I just want to know when to use OOP and when not to? If certain things can be managed without it, should I still use it?  Thanks

Comment: @ChaosPandion There should be an absolute logic in my mind before using OOP? Thanks

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to avoid applying different techniques as needed. You as the programmer will need to weigh the pros and cons on a case by case basis. Quite often it comes down to personal style.

Comment: If the assignment is to write a calculator using OOP, then that is the assignment.  Writing it without those techniques misses the point of the assignment and may make later ones harder having not understood the basics of the first. Sometime assignments are contrived for the point of specific tasks no matter how hard it is to do (I once wrote a maze generator in ML because I had to write it in ML - it wasn't anywhere near as elegant as the C one I wrote... But that was the assignment and I knew some ML then).

Comment: @MichaelT How do professional programmers make judgement call on whether to go for OOP or not? It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: I've never had it be an issue.  The language was nearly always a prescribed tool given the team and/or other architecture.

Comment: Is it OK to create things out of wood, when metals are available?

Comment: @whatsisname Houses are still made of woods? Buildings are made of steel. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the benefit of object-oriented programming over procedural programming?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120019/whats-the-benefit-of-object-oriented-programming-over-procedural-programming)

Comment: Implementing the same program with and without OO techniques is a **good** exercise to learn something, I cannot understand why some people here seem to deny this or downvote you. But the problem with your question is that it was already asked here more than once, in different forms. And though you deny it, you *are* asking about merits of Object Oriented Programming over procedural programming. And C++ is not an OO language, it is an hybrid language.

Comment: @DocBrown I am not asking about merits and demerits. Let me clear what I am asking. Lets assume grocery store is next block to my house, should I still go there by car to just buy a dozen of eggs? Or should I consider walking? I hope this might help you consider my question as not a duplicate.

Comment: So you would ask "what are the merits and demerits of using car".

Comment: I am asking when to use car and when not to. :) I already know what  are its merits & demerits.

Comment: You are playing with words, for a topic with no absolute "yes" or "no", that is the same question.

Comment: To add to @DocBrown's comment about C++ being a hybrid (or multi-paradigm) language, you might want to read Stroustrup's recent mini-series about five popular myths about C++, one being "C++ is an Object-Oriented Language". See here: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/12/myths-1

Comment: Add a feature that displays the formula you've entered and then add a square root function (Don't do this first, that would be cheating.) and let us know what you think.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

C++ is not "just" an OO language, it is a multi-paradigm language. So it allows you to decide for or against OO programming, or to mix them both. Using OO techniques adds more structure to your program - from which you will benefit when your program reaches a certain size or complexity. This additional structure, however, comes for the price of additional lines of code. So for "small" programs the best way to go is often to implement them in a non-OO style first, and add more and more OO techniques later when the program starts to grow over the years (which will probably not happen to "exercise" programs, but is the typical life cycle for lots of business programs).

The tricky part is not to miss the point in time when the complexity of your program reaches the size which demands more structure. Otherwise you will end up with a huge pile of spaghetti code.

Comment: If simple "exercise" programs starts to evolve, best way is to implement it in such a manner that it can be re factored afterwards. Thank you for sharing that :) +1

Comment: @CarlSmith: absolutely. But when I wrote my answer, I tried to focus on the points and scale of the actual question.

Answer (score 10):

> How do professional programmers make judgement call on whether to go
>   for OOP or not? It would be really helpful for me.

For me, there are two decision points. First, sometimes it will be obvious at the beginning. There will be lots of similar types that all share common methods that differ widely in their implementation details. For example, I was building a workflow system, and I needed the ability to implement arbitrary tasks. To run the task, I implemented a base class that each task inherited from, with an `Execute()` abstract method. The inheriting classes supplied the implementation, but the workflow system could begin the execution without knowing anything about what kind of task was being run.

Most projects aren't that clear-cut though. The second decision point is when a subset of the project has grown into a huge tangle of if-then statements or switch-case statements, and especially when those if-then statements require a lot of setup code to run correctly. I feel myself starting to lose the logic of what I'm trying to accomplish, and the code starts to feel fragile. At that point, it is usually a sign that it is time to refactor the code into base classes with specific implementations.

A big part of switching to an object-oriented style as opposed to a functional style is converting if-then statements into "run this action" statements. Instead of a huge set of if-then statements, you just tell the code to run its action. Which action is actually run depends on the implementation you supplied.

For example, here's the functional style in C#-style pseudocode:

```
if ( action == "email" ) { 
    callEmailFunction(userInfo);
}
else if ( action == "sms" ) { 
    callSmsFunction(userInfo);
}
else if ( action == "web" ) { 
    endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1/confirm";
    confirmWeb(endpoint, userinfo);
} 
...
```

But maybe you could rewrite that to something like this:

```
interface IConfirmable {
    void Confirm(UserInfo userinfo);
}

public class ConfirmEmail : IConfirmable { 
    public void Confirm(UserInfo userinfo) {
        // do the appropriate thing to confirm via email
    }
}

public class ConfirmSms : IConfirmable { 
    public void Confirm(UserInfo userinfo) {
        // do the appropriate thing to confirm via email
    }
}

public class ConfirmWeb : IConfirmable { 
    // this is a constructor
    public ConfirmWeb(string endpoint) { 
        ...
    }

    public void Confirm(UserInfo userinfo) {
        // do the appropriate thing to confirm via web
    }
}
```

And then the code itself:

```
// An implementation that decides which implementation of the base class to use
// This replaces the if-then statements in the functional programmming.
IConfirmable confirmer = ConfirmerFactory.GetConfirmer();

// get the userinfo however you get it, 
// which would be the same way you get it in the functional example.
UserInfo userinfo = ...;

// perform the action.
confirmer.Confirm(userinfo);
```

Now, when there is very little code inside the if-then, this looks like a lot of work to get no benefit. And when there is very little code in the if-then, that is correct: that's a lot of work for code that is harder to understand.

But the object-oriented style really shines when you have more than one action than just the `Confirm()` method that needs to be performed. Maybe you have an initialization routine, three or more action methods that can be run, and a `Cleanup()` method. The base algorithm is identical, except it makes its calls into the appropriate objects that implement a common base class. *Now* you start to see a real benefit to the object oriented style: the base algorithm is *much* easier to read than if it was checking if-then statements at every step of the way.

Comment: +1 for detailed analysis. :) I have few thoughts on this.

Comment: Aside: please stop posting "thanks" comments on every answer. We prefer to focus on just questions and answers, not discussion.

Comment: That example is more imperative than functional.

Comment: Cf. the [chain-of-responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: Just a note, when you're leaning towards a bunch of if/else or switch statements, it's always an option to consider some sort of lookupt table. So another way to rewrite that goes along the lines of `var dict = new Dictionary<string,Action<UserInfo>{ { "email", callEmailFunction }, { "sms", callSmsFunction } }; dict[ action ]( userInfo );` (dict can be static, error handling omitted)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is perfectly normal to use old style code, provided the scope of your project is well known or is limited. If you plan on extending your program or project OOP is one way to go, because you can maintain and extend your code seamlessly, on the other hand  if you planned it and have come to a conclusion that you are never going to plan extensibility of the project you make then writing code without OOP would suffice. It doesn't mean if you use non OOP approach you can never upgrade your project but then it would be a tedious thing to do. OOP is to help us visualize our concept as though it were a real life organism because we understand those better than anything else.

Comment: "It doesn't mean if you use non OOP approach you can never upgrade your project but then it would be a tedious thing to do.": OOP helps to extend your project when most extensions involve adding new classes (e.g. adding new widgets to a GUI). When most extensions involve adding new operations, then a procedural design can be more effective.

Comment: Since when is "not object oriented" called "old style"?

Comment: OOP was a fad, it has been progressively abandoned. I don't see it nearly as much as in the 90's and 2000's. Is OOP now considered 'old style'? Let's move on.